# Write join table data - has_many :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails

That should be a simple question but i can't find a good solution online.

I have three tables/models. User, Alliance and Alliance_Membership. The latter is a join table describing the :Alliance has_many :Users through :Alliance_Membership relationship.

Everything works ok, but Alliance_Membership now has an extra field called 'rank'. The question is, how do i set that when creating my new object ? Currently, i do something like :

```
@alliance.users << current_user
```

This is really convenient since it populates my Alliance_Membership table automatically. But, how can i set the Alliance_Membership.rank field as well ?

Comment: Does a user have multiple Alliances?

Comment: No, a user has one alliance, an alliance has many users through the membership table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to create the membership yourself to set the 'rank' attribute. Something like this:

```
  @alliance.alliance_memberships.create!(
    :user => current_user,
    :rank => 'whatever')
```

Comment: Works great thanx :) Small correction for people that look at it, it should be alliance_membership, but the technique is the same. Thanx Jeremy :)